# Removing Text and Comparing Integers within Strings

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, integer

Due to my original post being filled with flamers assuming that I'm asking them to write my code for me and refusing to answer me at all, I'm reposting my question.

I stress the fact that I am a total BEGINNER at Python, and that I am NOT here to ask people to write it for me, I'm simply trying to ascertain the METHOD and some GUIDANCE on how to approach the problem, because I'm having real difficulty approaching it, and everyone seems to think I'm asking them to give me all the code I need, and I'm not.

So, on to my original question.

My problem is as follows, I have made a mathematics quiz, that outputs the name and score to a text file. In this program, I plan to add some code at the beginning, which will run a list of options to compare and order the results from the text file. The program imports the entries into a list, and the format is as follows:

['John : 6', 'Bob : 9', 'Billy : 2', 'Matthew : 7', 'Jimmy : 2', 'Amy: 9', 'Jenny : 10', 'Michael : 8']

Python recognizes this list as 8 items, perfect. It has their name, and then their score. The problem is that the specification I'm working to requires me to be able to:

Sort in alphabetical order with each student's highest score for the tests.

Also, by the highest score, and finally by the average score. I've tried for many hours in order to find some code that can compare the integers within these strings to each other to find the highest score, and only print that one, but I've had no luck. I feel like I will also struggle with the other 2 tasks, and wish for some guidance.

I thought about possibly using slices in order to take the integer into a separate value in order to compare them, but felt that this could make the code messy very quickly.

Comment: The lists can have students with the same name?

Comment: Yes, it can, it must be able to recognize the entry with the highest integer.

Comment: So what you want is
1) Order by name, then by score (if two or more elements have the same name;

2) Order by score;

3 ) This is what I don't get, you want to get the average score of all scores?

Comment: Order alphabetically, and if there is 2 entries for the same person it should only print the highest of the entries for that student 2) Order by score, taking their highest and ignoring other entries 3) If more than one entry for the same student, calculate the average of their scores, and then order the average of each student high to low

Comment: Does that make more sense?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing Text and Comparing Integers within a String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32842141/removing-text-and-comparing-integers-within-a-string)

Comment: When you're told that your question should be improved, the correct action is _not_ to repost the same question while complaining about how poorly received it was.  Please [edit your _original_ question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/32842141/edit) to make it better.

Comment: Kevin, it's not that it was poorly written. It's that they thought I was asking them to write it for them. The fault was not mine.

Comment: I'm not going to go back and edit an already dead post, to improve it, when I'm actually getting help here, because they recognize I'm not asking them to do it for me. You don't realise it, but you're being anti-productive and actually hindering me in learning how to overcome the problem.

Comment: I can't understand point 3, you want to calculate the avg if there's more than one entry for a given student and then you want to sort the entire list (students with one entry or more included) ?

Comment: Calculate the average for each student, and then order the averages high to low

Comment: @ik0uuu Take a look at my answer, I have linked the pages for the official python documentation so you can have some guidance, I advice you to read them and try an approach of yours and only after you've tried something you should come here and compare your approaches with the provided answers. Good luck! :)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to split the strings on the " : " and then convert the number to int with `int("2")`.

The result can then be put in an dictionary:

```
d = {}
d['John'] = 6
```

If you already have an item (`if x in d:`), you could compare the old value and the new value.

Comment: Never use `has_key`; Python `dict`s have supported syntax based checks for membership for ages, and `has_key` has been deprecated the whole time (it's gone in Python 3).  `if d.has_key(x):` can be expressed canonically (and more efficiently to boot) as `if x in d:`.

Comment: Firstly, I'd like to thank you - exactly the kind of answer and guidance I was looking for, and the guidance provided has enabled me to understand where to approach from, I'll certainly go and practice dictionaries.

Comment: The only thing I'm now lost on is separating the integer from the string, and how I can add the name and integer to the dictionary even after the integer has been separated from the string, if that makes sense..

Comment: As you are learning, I would recommend you to google. For example: from my answer you could Ctrl+c Ctrl-v the "split the strings" and add "python" to the end and google will show you the answer.

Comment: I'll certainly do that, it's just that I'm struggling to understand how I will get the code to add each item from the list to the dictionary with the two bits separated.. how will it know what score belongs to which person after the initial separation?

Answer (score 0):

convert your list to  tuples and then it will be easy to sort
[sorting](https://docs.python.org/3.6/howto/sorting.html?highlight=sorting)

```
from operator import itemgetter

st = [('John',6), ('Bob',9), ('Billy', 8), ('Matthew',7),
      ('Jimmy',2), ('Amy', 9), ('Jenny',10),('Michael',8)]


print(sorted(st, key=itemgetter(1),reverse=True))

[('Jenny', 10), ('Bob', 9), ('Amy', 9), ('Billy', 8), ('Michael', 8), ('Matthew', 7), ('John', 6), ('Jimmy', 2)]
```

Comment: This seems like a highly efficient way of doing it, can you possibly explain to me exactly how this code works, or possibly point me somewhere I might read up on it to better understand what you've written?

Comment: Also, how might I go about converting the list?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a dictionary instead of your list.  Dictionaries work by pairing a key and a value.  For example:

```
d = {}
d = {'key':'value'}
```

To convert your list, you could split the strings for key and value using `:` as the point to split.  For example:

```
test = ('John : 2')
print (test.split(" : "))
```

returns:

```
['John', '2']
```

Putting it all together, here's a sample of code pulling in your list and converting it to dictionary and then sorting by name:

```
import operator

data = ['John : 6', 'Bob : 9', 'Billy : 2', 'Matthew : 7', 'Jimmy : 2', 'Amy : 9', 'Jenny : 10', 'Michael : 8']

new_data = {}
for i in range(len(data)):
    split_data = data[i].split(" : ")
    new_data[split_data[0]] = split_data[1]

new_data = sorted(new_data.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(0))
print (new_data)
```

Comment: So.. how would I get it to split all the items in the list, convert them all and append to a dict?.. Seems like I'm asking too much but an example would be highly appreciated if possible

Comment: Forgot about the sorting by name... added that.

Answer (score 0):

A list of key/value strings is not the appropriate data structure to address your problem, as it requires string manipulation to extract the values. You should probably parse your data into a [Dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) or list of tuples instead.

**using a dictionary**

```
d = {'John': 6, 'Bob': 9, 'Billy': 2, 
     'Matthew': 7, 'Jimmy': 2, 'Amy': 9, 
     'Jenny': 10, 'Michael': 8}
```

you could then do

```
# highest score
hs_name = max(d, key=d.get) 
hs = d.get(hs_name)

output = "The winner is {} ({} Points)".format(hs_name, hs)
print(output)
```

Dictionaries do not have an order in memory but you can get a sorted representation of them:

```py
# print ordered
import operator
sorted_d = sorted(d.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

print(sorted_d)
```

If you want to store a dictionary in memory in an ordered way, you may consider using [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

You could also consider using a list of key/value pairs as your data structure:

**using a list of tuples**

```
lt = [('John', 6), ('Bob', 9), ('Billy', 2), 
      ('Matthew', 7), ('Jimmy', 2), ('Amy', 9), 
      ('Jenny', 10), ('Michael', 8)]

# print ordered
sorted_lt = sorted(lt, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(sorted_lt)

# highest score
hs_name = sorted_lt[0][0]
hs = sorted_lt[0][1]

output = "The winner is {} ({} Points)".format(hs_name, hs)
print(output)
```

I have no idea what your specific requirements are and what average you want to sort by (there is only one value per student after all) but this should give you an idea.

Comment: I'll certainly be sure to investigate this and see what I come up with, thanks so much for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not the most pythonic way to do this (I left comments in the code, I hope you understand, if not just ask):

```
#Your input list (changed so you can check your requirements when there's two scores for the same person)
input_list = ['John : 6', 'Bob : 10', 'Bob : 9', 'Billy : 2', 'Matthew : 7', 'Jimmy : 2', 'Amy: 9', 'Jenny : 10', 'Michael : 8']

#Transform into a List of tuples
scores = [(item.split(":")[0].strip(), item.split(":")[1].strip()) for item in input_list]

"""CASE 1 - Order alphabetically, and if there is 2 entries for the same person it should only print the highest of the entries for that student"""

print("Entering Case 1")

#create a dictionary with names and delete duplicates (save only the highest score for a given student)
dictionary_by_names = dict()

for item in scores:
    if item[0] not in dictionary_by_names:
        dictionary_by_names[item[0]] = item[1]
    else:
        dictionary_by_names[item[0]] = max(int(item[1]), int(dictionary_by_names[item[0]]))

#order by name (List of tuples)
list_by_names = sorted([(key,value) for key, value in dictionary_by_names.items()])

print(list_by_names)

"""CASE 2 - Order by score, taking their highest and ignoring other entries"""
print("Entering Case 2")

#invert dictionary_by_names, since we only want the highest score of a given duplicate
dictionary_by_scores = [(int(value), key) for key, value in dictionary_by_names.items()]

#Sort the list formed from the dictionary (cast the score to int so we can perform sort of int instead of string, because '10' < '2'  (strings) and 10 > 2 (int))
list_by_score = sorted([(key,value) for key, value in dictionary_by_scores])
#Cast to string again so we can have it in the "original format"
list_by_score = [(str(item[0]), item[1]) for item in list_by_score]
#Invert tuples order so we can have it in the "original format"
list_by_score = [(item[1], item[0]) for item in list_by_score]

print(list_by_score)


"""CASE 3 - If more than one entry for the same student, calculate the average of their scores, and then order the average of each student high to low"""
print("Entering Case 3")

#create a dictionary with names and averages for students
dictionary_by_avg = dict()

for item in scores:
    if item[0] not in dictionary_by_avg:
        dictionary_by_avg[item[0]] = float(item[1])
    else:
        dictionary_by_avg[item[0]] = sum([float(item[1]), float(dictionary_by_avg[item[0]])])/2

list_by_avg = sorted([(value,key) for key, value in dictionary_by_avg.items()])
#Invert tuples order so we can have it in the "original format"
list_by_avg = [(item[1], item[0]) for item in list_by_avg]

print(list_by_avg)
```

Output:

```
Entering Case 1
[('Amy', '9'), ('Billy', '2'), ('Bob', 10), ('Jenny', '10'), ('Jimmy', '2'), ('John', '6'), ('Matthew', '7'), ('Michael', '8')]
Entering Case 2
[('Billy', '2'), ('Jimmy', '2'), ('John', '6'), ('Matthew', '7'), ('Michael', '8'), ('Amy', '9'), ('Bob', '10'), ('Jenny', '10')]
Entering Case 3
[('Billy', 2.0), ('Jimmy', 2.0), ('John', 6.0), ('Matthew', 7.0), ('Michael', 8.0), ('Amy', 9.0), ('Bob', 9.5), ('Jenny', 10.0)]
```

Hope this is what you were trying to achieve, next time subdivide your problem and post chunks of code that you have tried I admit this problem is not linear, but you could have done parts of it.

Hope this helps.

BTW check some of the documentation that would have helped you:

[Data Structures](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)

[Control Flow Tools](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html)

I bet you could have built a solution of your own if you had read it. :)

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to achieve.. I cannot express enough thanks to you, although I would've benefitted from writing it myself. Thank you so much.

Comment: The only thing is, on Case 2 and 3, how might I order the scores high to low instead of low to high?

Comment: Well I'll let you find out that :) I think is a good exercise for you to understand this code and to change it. If you don't understand anything please do ask. =)

Comment: Okay, I absolutely understand that! I would've liked to write it myself, so I may possibly rewrite using your code as a foundation, I cannot thank you enough for your help and time - it's incredibly valuable to a beginner such as myself.

Comment: Sidenote - I cannot test currently, but I'm assuming it would work if before printing the list on case 2 and 3, if I make a new value and set it so it's = list_by_score.reverse() and then print the new value it would do what I'm asking?

Comment: No problem, at all we have all been there, some just forget it sooner than other. Just as recommendation, please do post some code of yours next time, the input and expected output, show us something that you have done in order to achieve your goal or some people will take you as someone that just wants us to do your work.

Comment: I'll let you test it later, and check if that will work =)

Comment: I made a new value before you inverted the tuples, with .reverse() and it then successfully worked, thank you so much!

Comment: See? You found it by your own. If the answer pleases you please accept it and vote it. thanks! Glad to help!

Comment: Would it be possible fro you to initiate a chatroom with me or link me somewhere we can talk? I'm in need of some help that doesn't really warrant a new topic..

Comment: Can't you post your questins here? Thanks

Comment: In short, my problem is in regards to case 3. It doesn't actually calculate the averages properly, if you run it with this list: ['Roger : 9', 'John : 4', 'Bob : 3', 'Michael : 8', 'Billy : 8', 'Jimmy : 7', 'Amy : 10', 'Michael : 6', 'Amy : 9', 'Michael : 10', 'Jamie : 5', 'Jamie : 6', 'Jamie : 9', 'Jamie : 2']

Comment: You'll see exactly what I mean. It seems to be something to do with the fact that it skips over entries if there's more than 2 of the same person, if they're out of order [it doesn't do Amy because there's one in-between] and it also only divides by 2, not the amount of entries it added

Comment: Not too sure how to modify it to get it to do what I'm asking though

Comment: I'll take a look when I have a chance

Comment: Also just found one other problem if you could possibly take a look? In case 2, if you use the list I posted, that one also does not take the highest value if there is a lower value before a higher value.. any way to fix that? I presume it is also present in case 1.

Comment: Don't suppose you've had a chance to look at it yet?

Comment: Nop, sorry haven't got the time, at all, maybe over the weekend.

Comment: I'm still stumped on this, no matter how many times I look over it I just can't seem to figure out why it isn't working the way it should..

Comment: Haven't got the time to look at this, but I guess in "my" solution I've not considered repeated person names, try to change the dictionary `dictionary_by_names = dict()` to another data structure ([here](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html)) that allows you to have repeated valus, but if I remembered correctly you asked for deleting the dupliate names (in one case you wanted the average and the other you wanted the maximum between two scores for the same name).

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've figured out the point of error, thanks for all the help, it has been invaluable. Reading over some of the documentation and although it seems fairly complex, I'm happy that I'll be able to figure it out and rewrite the whole program into a perfectly working solution.

Comment: Congrats! That's The biggest asset you can have! :)